# Can the data transfer object`s data match the UI needs

Tags: asp.net-web-api, viewmodel, dto, data-transfer-objects

The data transfer object holds data from multiple business objects sent to the client.

But should/could this data and its structure be extra setup for the client to fit its binding needs?

Or should I extra create a ViewModel for this?

Its a small application so I am hesitating about too much overarchitecting and the dto`s would be 90% the same as the viewmodels...

The DTO`s would be transfered from a restful server to a javascript client not more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the thing to consider is what differences exist between the VM and DTO. A while back, I was attempting to create C# view models which implemented, derived from, or contained the DTO contract plus all the view centric stuff such as select list options and filter properties. I found this to be cumbersome, fragile and WET (as opposed to DRY ;).

I've since moved to a pattern of defining my view models in JavaScript and allowing the DTO objects to contain only the properties necessary to satisfy the contract expectations of the service layer. I pull data down using ajax. The data is typically passed into the view in the format it was received from the service. I then update my data-bound, observable knockout view models. So far, this pattern has been really productive for me.

With regard to input validation, so long as we're talking about validation attributes, I think it's perfectly fine that you have validation attributes defined on your DTO. After all, your API controller has a ModelState for a reason. Unfortunately, there's not a really good method to translate that validation into your client-bound views. As such, I've been leaning on knockout validation more than MVC's validation. I'm holding on to hope, however, that there is a better solution validation solution out there!

Comment: It is good that you mention ajax/knockout because I use them too on client side. Event more I do a SPA and I am faced with WET alot like ViewModels on client AND Server side...or go more DRY way and use DTO on server side and viewmodels(I would need them anyway there) on client side. Yes with input validation I mean validation attributes (Data Annotation attributes) or FluentValidation which worked well for me in asp.net mvc. Well knockoutjs validation is fine but its clientside(not secure) I need proper server side validation too(modelstate)

Answer (score 0):

I like to consider the representations that I retrieve as wire representations of my ViewModel.  In many cases there is no need to make a distinction between ViewModel and DTO.

Comment: The consequence would be that my structured DTO would be the input validation model on server side of my e.g. web api controller. You still agree?

Comment: @Elisa I don't share types between client and server so I don't run into this issue.  I also don't treat reads and writes as symmetric operations.  However, for simple scenarios you can probably get away with adding input validation onto your viewmodel/DTO.